# How do I use query with conditions and display last specified number of rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using QUERY to display specific columns of rows that meet a condition, but would also like to only display the last 3 rows, as shown, example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OGjg3aZ3eTEHdf_1xGjGiaGc-hV4-X75AIsK372Zwfg/edit?usp=sharing):

[image: example]

If I use this formula in Cell H2, I get the data I need but not just a specified number of rows: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:F8,ROW(A2:F8)},"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col6 where Col3='"&$H$1&"'",1))`

If I use this formula instead, I can get the last 3 rows, but not the specific data I need: `=QUERY(A2:F8,"select * offset "&COUNT(A2:A)-3)`

What's the best way to combine both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first formula you could sort in descending order that 7th column you added and limit 3:

```
=QUERY({A2:F8,INDEX(ROW(A2:F8))},"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col6 where Col3='"&$H$1&"' order by Col7 desc limit 3",1)
```

Other option is to use FILTER to get the three last rows without modifying the order. It filters according to the total number of rows and gets the three highest values

```
=LET(q,QUERY({A2:F8},"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col6 where Col3='"&$H$1&"'",1),
FILTER(q, SEQUENCE(ROWS(q))>(ROWS(q)-3)))
```

Comment: Your other option works unless there are less than 3 matches found, which then returns the first row plus the other matches. If Column C contains numerical values, then I just get the first row.

Comment: The issue is not the way if finding the last values that we're providing, but the numerical values; when in your QUERY you're using single apostrophes you're converting it to text, then no matching with your  numeric column. You can use FILTER and TO_TEXT to get sure that everything is considered the same way: `=LET(q,FILTER(A2:F8,TO_TEXT(C2:C8)=TO_TEXT(H1)),FILTER(q,SEQUENCE(ROWS(q))>(ROWS(q)-3)))`

Comment: =LET(q,FILTER({A2:B8,E2:F8},TO_TEXT(C2:C8)=TO_TEXT(H1)),FILTER(q,SEQUENCE(ROWS(q))>(ROWS(q)-3)))

Comment: This one takes care of everything! Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({A2:F8},"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col6 where Col3='"&$H$1&"'",0),"Select * Offset " &COUNTIF(C2:C8,H1)-3)
```

**Result:**
[image]

---

**Explanation:**

Using `=QUERY({A2:F8},"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col6 where Col3='"&$H$1&"'",0)`
this will return the data based on the condition:
[image]

You may then use it with another query combined with `countif()` to offset and only get the last N number of columns.

You may refer to this reference link I've found for more details:
[Formula to Conditionally Filter Last N Rows in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/formula-to-conditionally-filter-last-n-rows-in-google-sheets/)

---

### Edit:

To make it work with numeric data, you have to format it to plain text. From the Menu select **Format** -> **Number** -> **Plain Text**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

To change the last N number of rows you want to keep, you just have to change the minus at the `countif()`

Comment: See if it's useful my update of the answer @J.Kubassek

Comment: If there is numeric data in Column C, it doesn't work unless I update the formula to this: =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A2:F8),"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col6 where Col3='"&$H$1&"'",0),"Select * Offset " &COUNTIF(C2:C8,H1)-3)) but then everything converts to text and I can't use the data in a chart. Is there a solution to treat only Column C as text and keep the remaining data as is? Also, how can I show the matches found if there are less than 3? You can see my updates on the Test sheet in my example link.

Comment: @J.Kubassek I have updated the posted answer to make it work with numeric data. Also if you want to change the last N number of rows you just have to change the minus at the countif which is found at the end of the formula. However if the actual data is less than the number of rows you are trying to show it will return an error, workaround for this is by adding an if statement.